# What is the applicationcontext in makeTest() Method, please explain with the following snippet

Tags: android

```
Toast.makeTest(HelloGridView.this,"Text to be displayed",Toast.LENGTH.SHORT).show();
```

What is the 'HelloGridView.this' refers? why it is called as appliactioncontext?

Comment: How come this was put in the community wiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called context because HelloGridView.this (Activity class) extends the Context class (not directly, but it extends another class, which extends another, which in turn extends the Context class).

It's a grand grand child of the Context class.